# Update UI using invoke and delegate

Tags: wpf, delegates, invoke

In WinForm, i used Invoke and delegate to update UI,it's normal.

```
   this.Invoke((EventHandler)(delegate { txData.Text = data; } ));
```

But in WPF ,i used the same, and the trouble is like this,it displayed "TargetParameterCountException" and "Parameter count mismatch",

```
   this.Dispatcher.Invoke((EventHandler)(delegate { txData.Text = data; } ));
```

So could you please advice of what may went wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try use the application Dispatcher for invoking method on the UI thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => SomeFoo()));
```

Or

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) (() => SomeFoo()));
```

Answer (score 0):

`EventHandler` is defined like this :

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

So, you need to pass required parameters,

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((EventHandler)(delegate { txData.Text = data; }), this, null);
```

But, standard way is this :

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { txData.Text = data; });
```

or,

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate { txData.Text = data; });
```